# Changing Bool for while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, scrapy

I am working on web scraping program and I need to use a while and I set it equal to till and it runs a few times then when j becomes equal to a certain number it changes the bool to false and exits the loop to go down to the following function to actually parse the data.  But I need it to re-enter the loop when it is ready to get the next url but with s still being False it will not enter it.  How can I change s back to true?

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    # Name of Spider
    name = 'splash_spider'
    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them
    def start_requests(self):
        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
           # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)
            j = 1
            s = True
            for i, req in enumerate(requests):
                import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                while s == True :
                    x = len(requests) - i
                    # Return needed url with set delay of 3 seconds
                    yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                            # Pair with user agent specified in csv file
                            headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                            # Sets splash_url to whatever the current proxy that goes with current URL  is instead of actual splash url
                            splash_url = req["ip"],
                            priority = x,
                            meta={'priority': x}  # <- check here!!
                            )

                    j = j + 1
                    if j == len(requests):
                        s = False
                        j = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a boolean. Use `while True:`, and then use `break` to exit the loop.

```
def start_requests(self):
    # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
    with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
       # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
        requests = process_csv(csv_file)
        j = 1
        for i, req in enumerate(requests):
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            while True :
                x = len(requests) - i
                # Return needed url with set delay of 3 seconds
                yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                        # Pair with user agent specified in csv file
                        headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                        # Sets splash_url to whatever the current proxy that goes with current URL  is instead of actual splash url
                        splash_url = req["ip"],
                        priority = x,
                        meta={'priority': x}  # <- check here!!
                        )

                j = j + 1
                if j == len(requests):
                    j = 1
                    break
```

But it seems like you don't need `while` or `j` at all, use `for _ in range(len(requests)):`

Also, you should set `x` outside the inner loop, since it doesn't change within that loop.

```
def start_requests(self):
    # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
    with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
       # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
        requests = process_csv(csv_file)
        for i, req in enumerate(requests):
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            x = len(requests) - i
            for _ in range(len(requests)):
                # Return needed url with set delay of 3 seconds
                yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                    # Pair with user agent specified in csv file
                    headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                    # Sets splash_url to whatever the current proxy that goes with current URL  is instead of actual splash url
                    splash_url = req["ip"],
                    priority = x,
                    meta={'priority': x}  # <- check here!!
                    )
```

Comment: The reason I was doing this, it did not fix my problem though, is for my scrapy program I am scraping manyURLs and right now it is not scraping each URL in its entirety before moving on.  Each URL has several pages and it will scrape all the page 1s than page 2's and so on so I tried to set priorities to get the program to scrape on url completely before moving on to next one.  But it still did work.  Now though it is scraping two URLs  so its doing better.  So it will scrape page 1 or URL 1 than page 2 of URL 2 than back and forth until one is finished than it would move on two next URL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like if you simply re-assign `s` to false where you import ipdb, that would do the trick:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    # Name of Spider
    name = 'splash_spider'
    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them
    def start_requests(self):
        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
           # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)
            j = 1
            for i, req in enumerate(requests):
                s = True
                import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                while s == True :
                    x = len(requests) - i
                    # Return needed url with set delay of 3 seconds
                    yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                            # Pair with user agent specified in csv file
                            headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                            # Sets splash_url to whatever the current proxy that goes with current URL  is instead of actual splash url
                            splash_url = req["ip"],
                            priority = x,
                            meta={'priority': x}  # <- check here!!
                            )

                    j = j + 1
                    if j == len(requests):
                        s = False
                        j = 1
```